# Google Analytics: Tracking User Registration/Membership upgrades

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm fairly new to Google Analytics and im building a membership base site. GA seems to be very good at describing visits and user behavior, but I want to customize it so that it also tracks  track the number of user registrations and the number of users that upgraded their membership. I simply want to build a counter for those two fields and I was wondering what is the best approach?

My best guess is event tracking. Every time the user registers or upgrades their membership, i'll paste in the necessary js to register that as an event. I have never done this before so I'm not sure what's the best approach. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to make some custom tags :) This should get you started:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

This should also help:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#EventHandlers

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** If all that you need to do is maintain counter, event would be a good approach, you can refer the link mentioned by @Ryan Brodie. Also, storing the counter in the table can be an option :P.

**Case 2:** If you want to maintain the counter + study the visitor behavior of various categories of users you can opt for Custom Variables.Now say your website offers users the ability to login, you can use a custom variable scoped to the session level for user login status. In that way, you can segment visits by those from logged in members versus anonymous visitors. For more details visit 
[this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)